# fancyhdr with 2 different fonts

Tags: fonts, header-footer, lyx, fancyhdr

I need to write a footer with these requirements:

Font for footer – page # Garamond 12 regular, right upper corner, start page 1 with title & authors (after cover page)

· Rest of the footer. Font in Word will be Josefin Slab 9.5. Color should be certified from: http://curry.virginia.edu/uploads/resourceLibrary/Center_colors_with_s.jpg

I'm having troubles writing the code to have the page number be Garamond 12 regula while the rest of the footer Josefin Slab 9.5

Help will be much appreciated.

LyX document: https://www.dropbox.com/s/pmjfirn6qq9av5g/fancyhdr_question.lyx

LaTeX document: https://www.dropbox.com/s/jko0wujfxybzxfx/fancyhdr_question.tex

Thanks!

Comment: Does the following question help? [How do I use a particular font for a small section of text in my document?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25249)

Answer (score 1):

Using XeTeX allows me to solve the problem

```
\usepackage[urw-garamond]{mathdesign}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\definecolor{darkgreen}{cmyk}{0.5, 0, 1, 0.5}
\definecolor{lightgoldenrodyellow}{cmyk}{0,0,0.16,0.02}
\usepackage{framed}
\setlength\parindent{24pt}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\makeatletter
\definecolor{curry}{RGB}{72,121,131}
%\fancyfoot[RO, LE] {\color{black} \thepage}
\patchcmd{\@fancyfoot}{\rlap}{\color{curry}\rlap}{}{}
\makeatother
\fancyhead[LE,LO]{}
\newfontfamily\JosefinSlab{Josefin Slab}
\fancyfoot[C]{\color{black} {\hfill \thepage}\\
{\JosefinSlab \color{curry} \fontsize{9.5}{10} \selectfont  CEPWC Working Paper Series No. 19 December 2013.\\
Available at \url{ http://curry.virginia.edu/research/centers/cepwc/publications}.\\
Curry School of Education | Frank Batten School of Leadership and Public Policy | University of Virginia}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.0pt}
\fancyhead[R]{Martinez -- Lessons from a MOOC}
```